# Passing objects and a list of objects by reference in C#

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I have a delegate that modifies an object. I pass an object to the delegate from a calling method, however the calling method does not pick up these changes. The same code works if I pass a `List` as the object.

I thought all objects were passed by reference so any modifications would be reflected in the calling method. Is that correct?

I can modify my code to pass a `ref` object to the delegate. But I am wondering why this is necessary. Or is it?

```
public class Binder
{
    protected delegate int MyBinder<T>(object reader, T myObject);

    public void BindIt<T>(object reader, T myObject)
    {
        //m_binders is a hashtable of binder objects
        MyBinder<T> binder = m_binders["test"] as MyBinder<T>;
        int i = binder(reader, myObject);
    }
}

public class MyObjectBinder
{
    public MyObjectBinder()
    {
        m_delegates["test"] = new MyBinder<MyObject>(BindMyObject);
    }

    private int BindMyObject(object reader, MyObject obj)
    {
        obj = new MyObject
        {
            //update properties
        };
        return 1;
    }
}

///calling method in some other class
public void CallingMethod()
{
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();

    MyObjectBinder binder = new MyObjectBinder();
    binder.BindIt(myReader, obj); //don't worry about myReader

    //obj should show reflected changes
}
```

**Update:**

I am now passing objects by `ref` to the delegate as I am instantiating a new object inside `BindMyObject`.

```
protected delegate int MyBinder<T>(object reader, ref T myObject);
```

Comment: I realize you're trying to hide original names, here, but you've got to clean this up. `MyBinder` inside `CallingMethod` isn't definied, `MyObjectBinder` isn't used... are they the same? I can only try to assume, and I don't want to do that...

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Objects aren't passed by reference. Objects aren't passed at all.

By default, the value of the argument is passed by value - whether that value is a value type value or a reference. If an object is modified via that reference, then that change will be visible to the calling code as well.

In the code you showed originally, there was no reason to use `ref`. The `ref` keyword is used when you want a method that changes the value of a *parameter* (e.g. to make it refer to a different object entirely) and have that change visible to the caller.

Now, in the code you've shown (originally) you've only got:

```
private int BindMyObject(object reader, MyObject obj)
{
    //make changes to obj in here
}
```

Do you mean code like this:

```
private int BindMyObject(object reader, MyObject obj)
{
    obj = new MyObject();
}
```

or code like this:

```
private int BindMyObject(object reader, MyObject obj)
{
    obj.SomeProperty = differentValue;
}
```

? If it's the latter, then you don't need `ref`. If it's the former, then you *do* need `ref` because you're changing the parameter itself, not making changes to the object that the value refers to. In fact, if you're *just* setting the value of `obj` without ever reading it, you should use `out` instead of `ref`.

If you can show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates your problem, it'll be a lot easier to explain what's going on.

It's hard to do this topic justice in just a few paragraphs - so I've got an [entire article about it](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html), which will hopefully make things more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Yes, the problem was because in the BindMyObject I was initializing a new object. Just found this out debugging myself.

Comment: @David Liddle - You might want to include the changed code in your original topic that way people see what you ended up using.  So I take it you DID end up using REF being that your code new'ed a new myObject?

Comment: @JonH: I've modified my answer a little bit to make it clearer now that the code has been changed :)